# Is it possible to drill down the resultset of Q & A in power bi dashboard

Tags: powerbi

I have a dashboard created and when I use Q&A for some insights, I get the result in some visualization or table form. But with the result, I can't drill down to see the records which are part of it.[Snapshot of the Q&A in Power BI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikcW3.png).
Is it possible to get the data of how many are female and male based on the result of Q&A? If so, please let me know how to achieve it in power bi or by integrating some other tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Image you shared, you have already got the Male , Female Count using Q&A. What I can understand is, you want to know details of those customers who contributed to the count shown?

To achieve this, you will need to have a mapping between your Orders and your customer lookup table.

I have used the AdventureWorks DB, and tried to achieve solution.

1. I have taken the Employees table, having gender classification of employee
2. I have taken the PurchaseOrderHeader Table having which employee placed the order

I created a Report showing the "# of Orders placed by each employee" .[Dashboard of Adventureworks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FT8P2.jpg), now i have used Q&A to find "Employees by Gender" who have placed these orders [Out of 12 Employees 4 were Female](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5QgJZ.jpg), now to find the details of the employees , I changed the Q&A to find "Employees by Gender in Employee" , [This shows the details of each employee who contributed to order placements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/evKHu.jpg)

Hope this serves the query you had.

Basically, the lookup table should be there & in the Q&A you need to refer to lookup table to see the details.

Regards,

Kunal Kumar Shah

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. It did work for the above scenario.

I have another scenario,
Lets say,
 I search "Customers with last name 'Ben' " in Q&A.
 I get four customers as a result. 
Is it possible to select one of the customer(say, Frank Ben), which in turn displays all his details along with transaction?
Is drilling down in the result level of Q&A possible?

Comment: The approach you are asking is not drilling down, but doing a drill down to the customer name and then drill up to see which all orders are placed by that customer. 

There is no straight forward way to achieve it 

One Tip to remember : what Q&A does is create Smart Visualization by understanding the context. If your query is to satisfy a PowerBI developer, then he can change the visualization after Q&A is done, check the right panel. If your question is for ease of customer, then you better create a report for such requirement, where slicer of User Name is given and report shown